# Change CSS Styles BurguerMenu NavBar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a Bootstrap Navbar and I want that when I click on deploy button, this CSS (of the button) changes (I do not like CSS Button default). So... I want next:

- When I click on Menu (in Xtra Small Sizes -as movile-) its CSS Styles change (eg: background-color: red).

How could I do this? What is his ClassNameCss? (eg: .navbar button[aria-expanded=true]) Thank you.

EDIT: Added my NavBar Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-collapse-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Menú</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                {/*<a class="navbar-brand" href="/inicio"><img id="idFotoLogotipo" width="200px" src="./assets/images/cabecera_CE.jpg"/></a>*/}
                <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-block" /*href="http://www.upct.es/"*/><span id="idTextoLogotipo">- INCIDENCIAS -</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <MenuNavItem to='/administrador/inicio' index={true} /*menuItemActive="inicio"*/>Inicio</MenuNavItem>
                    <MenuNavItem to='/administrador/nueva_incidencia' /*menuItemActive="nueva_incidencia"*/>Nueva Incidencia</MenuNavItem>
                    <MenuNavItem to='/administrador/incidencias_recibidas' /*menuItemActive="incidencias_recibidas"*/>Incidencias Recibidas</MenuNavItem>
                    <MenuNavItem to='/administrador/informes' /*menuItemActive="informes"*/>Informes</MenuNavItem>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="divider visible-xs-block"></li>
                    {this.state.logged === true ? <p class="nav navbar-text hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Bienvenido, {this.state.nombre} ({this.state.dni})</p> : ''} 
                    {this.state.logged === true ? <p class="nav navbar-text visible-xs-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Bienvenido, {this.state.nombre}</p> : ''}
                    {this.state.logged === true ? <li class="salir"><a href="http://www.upct.es/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Salir</a></li> : <li class="entrar"><a href="http://www.upct.es/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Entrar</a></li>}
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the 'burger menu' (three lines) dropdown toggle button shown here:

[image: dropdown toggle button]

Then you should be able to target this with:

```
.navbar-toggle[aria-expanded="true"],
.navbar-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Note that the `:focus` style is required as otherwise the default grey background colour will still show when the button is clicked, as at that point the button will have focus.

**EDIT**: try this example - I've since prefixed the styles with `.navbar-default`, which should ensure the styles work.

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle[aria-expanded="true"],
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:focus {
    background-color: red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse[aria-expanded="true"] {
    background-color: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: I delete [aria-expanded="true"] and always take red color, not only when menu is deployed

Comment: I wanna do next: .navbar-default .navbar-toggle WHEN .navbar-collapse.collapse[aria-expanded=true] {
    background-color: #428bca;
}. How could I do this?

Comment: I do not know how this WHEN is translated into CSS language

Comment: I added my Navbar code into my question. My code is equals as yours, but it continue not working on me. I do not understand...

Comment: See above - demo updated to apply `#428bca` background colour to dropdown menu. Check which version of Bootstrap you're using (my demo uses the latest 3.3.7 build), so this may affect it.  Failing that, try to recreate your menu using the demo markup shown on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default as a starting point.

Comment: I am usign v. 3.3.7 too.. It is all equal... I used !important; too, but does not work. [aria-expanded=true] is not recognoised... :|